# With QBXML how can I unapply a transaction from a ReceivePayment from the remote system?

Tags: payment, quickbooks, qbxml, qbwc

I want to unapply a payment from an invoice from the remote system.

First I sync from QuickBooks Desktop a `ReceivePayment` item.  It has 1 invoice transaction in `AppliedToTxnRet` of the `ReceivePaymentQueryRS` response.

Then on the remote system the transaction is removed from the invoice.  So now there are no transactions that this payment is applied to.  In QBXML how can I specify this in the `ReceivePaymentModRq` or is there some other way to specify it to send it back to QuickBooks so that the payment is no longer applied to the invoice in QuickBooks?

I tried to send an empty `<AppliedToTxnMod/>` or `<AppliedToTxnMod></AppliedToTxnMod>` like this:

```
        <ReceivePaymentModRq>
            <ReceivePaymentMod>
                <TxnID>612-1631305229</TxnID>
                <EditSequence>1631418450</EditSequence>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>80000089-1613077827</ListID>
                </CustomerRef>
                <ARAccountRef>
                    <ListID>8000001B-1578805288</ListID>
                </ARAccountRef>
                <TxnDate>2021-09-04</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>cash11</RefNumber>
                <TotalAmount>11.00</TotalAmount>
                <PaymentMethodRef>
                    <ListID>80000001-1578006261</ListID>
                </PaymentMethodRef>
                <Memo/>
                <DepositToAccountRef>
                    <ListID>80000021-1620340635</ListID>
                </DepositToAccountRef>
                <AppliedToTxnMod/>
            </ReceivePaymentMod>
        </ReceivePaymentModRq>
```

But the validator gives me:

```
Line: 13
LinePos: 48
Src Text: <AppliedToTxnMod></AppliedToTxnMod>
Reason: Element cannot be empty according to the DTD/Schema.
```

I was going off of what I thought the QBSDK was saying (https://static.developer.intuit.com/resources/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf) on p. 126 for clearing an aggregate, but I guess maybe that doesn't apply to aggregates that reference other transactions??:

"Clearing an aggregate such as an address or shipping address is similar to clearing a
reference in a Modify request. You can either provide empty versions of all the elements in
the aggregate, or you can simply provide an empty aggregate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unapply a payment from a transaction, such as an invoice, in the `<ReceivePaymentMod>` send the `<AppliedToTxnMod>` aggregate referencing the `<TxnID>` that you want to remove with a zero amount in `<PaymentAmount>`.  For example:

```
<ReceivePaymentMod>
    <TxnID>612-1631305229</TxnID>
    ...
    <AppliedToTxnMod>
        <TxnID>52F-1630633150</TxnID>
        <PaymentAmount>0.00</PaymentAmount>
    </AppliedToTxnMod>
</ReceivePaymentMod>
```